# R - Importing 'xlsx' package to my own package doesn't work

Tags: r, xlsx, devtools, roxygen2

I am creating my own package. I am using a lot of existing packages in it and they work. I am using the same procedure for the `xlsx` package but it doesn't work. I have `xlsx` in `Imports:` in my `DESCRIPTION` file. I have `@import xlsx` in my respective .R file. I also tried `@importFrom write.xlsx` for a particular function with the same result. I am using libraries `devtools` and `roxygen2` for creating the package. My new package is build, but if I proceed `Check`, an error occurs:

```
Installation failed.
See 'C:/Work/Package/MyPackage.Rcheck/00install.out' for details.
* DONE
Status: 1 ERROR
Warning: running command '"C:/R/R-3.3.3/bin/x64/Rcmd.exe" INSTALL -l "C:/Users/Work/Package/MyPackage.Rcheck" --no-html "C:\Users\Work\Package\MyPackage.Rcheck\00_pkg_src\MyPackage"' had status 1
```

and

```
checking whether package 'MyPackage' can be installed ... ERROR
Installation failed.
See 'C:/Users/Work/Package/MyPackage.Rcheck/00install.out' for details.
R CMD check results
```

But there is no `.out` file from the error. The whole file `MyPackage.Rcheck` occurs for a short time during the checking process, but then it disappears. So I am not able to check the `.out` file and find an error.

I also tried to use command `library(xlsx)` inside my code. In this situation the process of building and checking has less problems. There is only one warning and one note:

```
WARNING
'library' or 'require' call not declared from: 'xlsx'
'library' or 'require' call to 'xlsx' in package code.
Please use :: or requireNamespace() instead.
See section 'Suggested packages' in the 'Writing R Extensions' manual.

NOTE
MyFunction: no visible global function definition for 'write.xlsx'
```

But I know that if I would like to upload my code to the CRAN there should not be any warnings.

I also know that `xlsx` package has two dependencies: `rJava` and `xlsxjars`. If I put them to `Imports:` in `DESCRIPTION` file and also use the `@import` in my .R file the same problem appears. I also tried used `Depends:` with the same results.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: I have the same experience of not being able to check `MyPackage.Rcheck` when building from RStudio. Try to build directly from the command line.

Comment: Or, as I just discovered, there are two options in RStudio: "Cleanup output after successful R CMD check" and "View Rcheck directory after failed R CMD check"

Comment: Thank you @Aurèle, it worked. Now I see the file. It seems that my problem is `rJava` problem.

Comment: Other suggestion: go to https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/index.html, See the `Reverse dependencies` section, pick one of those packages, and look up their source code to see how they deal with `xlsx`, take `qdap` for instance: https://github.com/trinker/qdap . You can simply read the source, or clone their repo and try to build locally, see if you can reproduce your issue ... or maybe take a simpler one like https://github.com/rOpenGov/psData

Comment: Thank you @Aurèle. In the codes from `Reverse dependencies` they use the standard `@import xlsx`. From the `.out` file, it seems that the problem is in Java on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

By disabling RStudio option "Cleanup output after successful R CMD check" I found the `.out` file. The problem was in Java on my computer. I am using 64-bit version of R and I have also 64-bit version of Java. So the package `xlsx` normally worked. But I have also installed 32-bit version of R on my computer but there was no 32-bit version of Java. After installing it, everything works. Every version of R must have the same version of Java. An oppositely, there must not be Java version without R opposite.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue over and over running in a Linux environment without the usage of Rstudio.

My issue was `@importFrom xlsx read.xlsx`, removing this and adding a call `xlsx::read.xlsx('myFile.xlsx', 1)` in the code where `read.xlsx` is used, then running `R -e "devtools::document()` works properly. After this, I've added again `@importFrom xlsx read.xlsx` and removed the `xlsx::` and then is working just fine.

I think this could be something related to first setting up configurations from `xlsx` package since before doing this I never made a call from it.