# In R, how to install packages used my own package automatically?

Tags: r, installation, package-development

This question is near to the following site:

[R - Importing 'xlsx' package to my own package doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43738366/r-importing-xlsx-package-to-my-own-package-doesnt-work)

I made some package, named `aa`,  in some computer in which installations go well.

When I try to install my own package in another computer, then the following error message occurs:

```
==> Rcmd.exe INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source aa

* installing to library 'C:/Users/aaaaaaaaaaa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5'
ERROR: dependencies 'knitr', 'rstan', 'readxl', 'testdat', 'openxlsx', 'xlsx', 'gridExtra' are not available for package 'aa'
* removing 'C:/Users/aaaaaaaaaaa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/aa'
In R CMD INSTALL

Exited with status 1.
```

By my hand, once I installed the package `knitr` which is described in above error, then error message is the following from which the package `knitr` disappears:

```
==> Rcmd.exe INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source aa

* installing to library 'C:/Users/aaaaaaaaaaa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5'
ERROR: dependencies 'rstan', 'readxl', 'testdat', 'openxlsx', 'xlsx', 'gridExtra' are not available for package 'aa'
* removing 'C:/Users/aaaaaaaaaaa/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/aa'
In R CMD INSTALL

Exited with status 1.
```

What I want to know is that the packages used in my own packages are automatically installed or not.

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907937/how-to-install-dependencies-when-using-r-cmd-install-to-install-r-packages

Comment: If you want to install package automatically, you must publish your package to CRAN

Comment: It depends how you install the package. If you install from GitHub/a repo with devtools and the dependencies are listed in Depends or Imports in the DESCRIPTION file, they should get automatically installed. With that particular set of packages, there's a very high likelihood at least one will fail, though, as knitr requires pandoc, rstan requires a compiler, and xlsx requires rJava, which requires lots of things it'd rather not tell you.

Comment: This is a quick note to thank @Chris, I try to understand your suggested page. It is hard for me.

Comment: Thanks for reply @alistaire. If the package's contains many requires which cause failures, then is it better to delete the packages from NAMESPACE and DESCRIPTION ? Since if I remain required packages in  NAMESPACE and DESCRIPTION, then it reads us to fail install.

Comment: You can't really remove them, because even if it will let you install your package, it will error out when the code that uses the imported function gets called. Assemble your DESCRIPTION so it passes `R CMD check`.

Comment: Thank your for your reply,@alistaire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try the easier way like this :
Add the following code in your `.R` file

```
tryCatch({
  library(knitr)
}, error = function(e) {
  install.packages("knitr")
  library(knitr)
})
```

Or

```
if("knitr" %in% installed.packages()[,1]){
  library(knitr)
}else{
  install.packages("knitr")
  library(knitr)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick, kind reply. Your suggested code is the one what I wanted to. I think If I replace `library()` to your suggested code in all files whose extension is `.R`, then the code will go well without attention to installations of packages in my own code.  However, I cannot install my package, so I cannot execute my codes, and hence I cannot execute your suggested code.